# How to get "Epson Printer Utility" to start from Launcher in Ubuntu?

Tags: printing, epson

There is "Epson Printer Utility" that shows ink levels and allows to check nozzles and clean printer heads. This utility appeared not long ago and it is very useful, because there is no other way to see ink levels for printers without LED using Linux systems.

[image]

The utility can be downloaded from [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).

After the deb package is installed the utility can be started by

```
epson-printer-utility
```

terminal command.

How can I get set it up to be started a normal way from Launcher or a desktop icon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create a `desktop` file for it and change some permissions.

1. Create `/usr/share/applications/epson-utility.desktop` file with this content:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Type=Application
   Categories=Application;Printing;

   Name=Epson Printer Utility

   Exec=epson-printer-utility
   Terminal=false
   Icon=/opt/epson-printer-utility/resource/Images/AppIcon.png
   ```
2. Give permissions to this file to be run

   ```
   sudo chmod +x /usr/share/applications/epson-utility.desktop
   ```
3. There are no permissions to read contents of `/opt/epson-printer-utility/resource/Images` directory for some reason. You need to grant them.

   ```
   sudo chmod 755 /opt/epson-printer-utility/resource/Images
   ```

Now you will see the utility in your Launcher.

[image]

Comment: Following the steps the icon is visible in the launcher, but its not opening, neither from the terminal. If invoked from terminal its showing Communication daemon down, Error code = -1. What  to do?

Answer (score 6):

I did alt+F2 and epson-printer-utility and then locked the icon on panel, plain and simple.

Comment: This looks like a commentary, not an answer.

Comment: This provides the easiest way to add to the launcher.

Comment: I like it. It's short and effective. +1

Comment: I couldn't find the lock to panel option in Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using gnome-panel to create an icon for it. You can install gnome-panel (from the terminal) with:

`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel --no-install-recommends`

and then start it (again from the terminal) with:

`sudo gnome-desktop-item-edit /usr/share/applications/ --create-new`

Then enter the name you would like the icon to have, the terminal command to start it, and a file path to a picture for the icon you want.

Comment: Is there a need to install gnome-panel just to run one program? The point was that there is an utility and it is possible to make a shortcut.