# Cannot start epson-printer-utility

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 x64 from 14.04 with a clean install. I used epson-printer-utility on 14.04 with no problems.  Now, when I try to launch it, I get the following message:

Communication daemon down, Error code = -1

I created a .desktop file and granted permissions according to this link:

[How to get "Epson Printer Utility" to start from Launcher in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752763/how-to-get-epson-printer-utility-to-start-from-launcher-in-ubuntu)

I had no problems in 14.04 with this program.  Also, everything is working fine with my printer in 16.04 wrt printing. I am not sure to what communications deamon the message is referring. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the error still showing wrt printing?

Comment: The utility works for me on 16.04.

Comment: No, there are no errors while printing.  Also, CUPS shows the printer is active and all other parameters seem to be in order.

Comment: A little more information: From CUPS I have                                                Driver: Epson Artisan 1430 Series - epson-inkjet-printer 1.0.0-1lsb3.2 (Seiko Epson Corporation LSB 3.2) (color)                                                                       
Connection: usb://EPSONArtisan%201430?serial=4E414D593038313832

Comment: Can confirm this also happens on 20.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just run this to start backend:

```
sudo systemctl start ecbd.service
```

Answer (score 2):

After installing the Epson Printer Utility, and using the instructions found at [How to get "Epson Printer Utility" to start from Launcher in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752763/how-to-get-epson-printer-utility-to-start-from-launcher-in-ubuntu) to create a .desktop file, you just have to reboot the computer to get rid of the communication daemon error.